# Merge two n number of array of objects based on a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays:

Array 1:

```
[
    {old_clicks: 1, date: "2017-01-24" }, 
    { old_clicks: 4, date: "2017-01-22" },
    { old_clicks: 6, date: "2017-01-21" }
]
```

and array 2:

```
[
    { total_clicks:120, date: "2017-01-21" },
    { total_clicks: 100, date: "2017-01-19" }
]
```

I need to merge these two arrays based on `date` and get this:

```
[
    { old_clicks: 1,date: "2017-01-24", total_clicks: 0 },
    { old_clicks: 4, date: "2017-01-22", total_clicks: 0 },
    { old_clicks: 6, date: "2017-01-21", total_clicks: 120 },
    { old_clicks: 0, date: "2017-01-19", total_clicks: 100 },
]
```

I have tried this but this is not working as its not merging properly.

```js
const arr1 = [
    { old_clicks: 1, date: "2017-01-24" }, 
    { old_clicks: 4, date: "2017-01-22" },
    { old_clicks: 6, date: "2017-01-21" }
];


const arr2 =  [
    { total_clicks:120, date: "2017-01-21" },
    { total_clicks: 100, date: "2017-01-19" }
];
        

const mergeById = (a1, a2) => a1.map(itm => ({
    ...a2.find((item) => (item.date=== itm.date)),
    ...itm
}));

console.log(mergeById(arr1,arr2))
```

Comment: @mplungjan Please see the both arrays, as  date is not present on first array but its there  on second array.

Comment: @mplungjan i made edits in code for matching &item, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: yes, it was a typo, sorry my bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a case for [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in single output value.

The signature is:

```
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, [, index[, array]] )[, initialValue])
```

The approach here is to add items using their `date` property as a key to a "map" object that starts out initialized as an empty object, then summing in the clicks properties you care about. At the end, `result` will be an object and we can use `Object.values()` to turn it's values into an array. We choose to use an object internally here to for faster lookup of existing dates, you could reduce using an array instead, but naively using `arr.find` would net you a O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution.

```js
const arr1 = [
  { old_clicks: 1, date: "2017-01-24" },
  { old_clicks: 4, date: "2017-01-22" },
  { old_clicks: 6, date: "2017-01-21" }
];


const arr2 = [
  { total_clicks: 120, date: "2017-01-21" },
  { total_clicks: 100, date: "2017-01-19" }
];


const mergeById = (...arrs) => {

  const result = arrs.flat().reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.date] = {
      date: obj.date,
      total_clicks: (acc[obj.date]?.total_clicks ?? 0) + (obj?.total_clicks ?? 0),
      old_clicks: (acc[obj.date]?.old_clicks ?? 0) + (obj?.old_clicks ?? 0),
    }

    return acc;
  }, {})
  
  return Object.values(result);
}

console.log(mergeById(arr1, arr2))
```

Comment: I also like the `obj?.total_clicks ?? 0` - I used the  `?.` with `||` but yours is safer

Comment: I actually just learned `obj?.prop ?? default` today!

Comment: Me too :)  [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in combination with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) - I knew of the first and used the second but the combo is cool

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty straightforward implementation that uses an object as an intermediary map, and uses Object.assign to handle the property merges.

This implementation supports an arbitrary amount of input arrays to merge, and also supports any additional properties automatically.

It's not tied specifically to your example, it's a generic solution to the question of how to merge arrays of objects together by key.

Note that if both arr1 and arr2 define the same property (like old_clicks), the latest one would win.  This may or may not be what you want (you might want to add them together?)

```js
const arr1 = [
    { old_clicks: 1, date: "2017-01-24" },
    { old_clicks: 4, date: "2017-01-22" },
    { old_clicks: 6, date: "2017-01-21" }
];

const arr2 = [
    { total_clicks: 120, date: "2017-01-21" },
    { total_clicks: 100, date: "2017-01-19" }
];

function mergeByProperty(mergeProperty, defaults, ...arraysToMerge) {
    const mergeObj = {};

    arraysToMerge.forEach(function (arrayToMerge) {
        arrayToMerge.forEach(function (item) {
            const mergeValue = item[mergeProperty];

            if (mergeValue) {
                if (!mergeObj[mergeValue]) {
                    mergeObj[mergeValue] = Object.assign({}, defaults, item);
                }
                else {
                    Object.assign(mergeObj[mergeValue], item);
                }
            }
            else {
                // TODO Invalid item.  Throw an Error or skip it.
            }
        });
    });

    return Object.values(mergeObj);
}

function mergeByDate(...arraysToMerge) {
    return mergeByProperty("date", { old_clicks: 0, total_clicks: 0 }, ...arraysToMerge);
}

console.log(mergeByDate(arr1, arr2));
```